# How does AWS Glue Dynamic Frame partition a single file?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

Could someone explain me how does AWS Glue partition a single large file ?  If it is using spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes to convert the large file into partitions how to override it in glue job ?
I tried using sparkConf
`conf = SparkConf() conf.set('spark.files.maxPartitionBytes',41943040) # 40MB sc= SparkContext().getOrCreate(conf=conf)`

I am using **pyspark**.

Comment: Are you asking how to use Spark to write a single large file?

Comment: When spark reads a single large file it will split the large file into blocks of data correct ? I wanted to reduce the block size. By Default, the block size is 128 MB in spark. I am not sure what is the default block size in Glue. Also I would like to know how to reduce the block size so that the single large file can be split into multiple chunks of data.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to [enable the Spark UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui-jobs.html) while working with Glue. There you can debug if and how your configs are set.

In addition you can run `print(dynamic_frame.toDF().rdd.getNumPartitions())`
directly after reading the file, so you can check how many partitions you have.

Comment: 'print(dynamic_frame.toDF().rdd.getNumPartitions())' tried this and got the number of partitions. I wanted to increase the partition but I don't want to do repartition(). I wanted to reduce the block size from 128MB to 60 MB using the parameters spark.files.maxPartitionBytes or spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes. I am not sure how to use them in Glue. Could you please help me with that.

Comment: So setting the config as you have done should work. Can you check in the spark UI, or can you print the config?

Comment: Okay let me try this Thanks.